# How to prove simple vector identities like $(c+d)A=cA+dA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For my upcoming exam, I have to be able to prove the following four statements (among a bank of others). Though they are pretty obviously true, I'm struggling to come up with a way to prove them without using some kind of emphatic assertion. A picture with some explanation will suffice as proof, but I'm unsure of how to form any picture.

In the statements, lowercase letters are scalars, capital are vectors.

$$c(-A) = (-c)A = -(cA)$$

$$(c+d)A = cA + dA$$

$$(cd)A = c(dA)$$

Furthermore, up to this point in the lesson we have not defined any useful notions of vector algebra (such as using basis vectors to write $A = a_1 i + a_2 j + a_3 k$), so we can't use that either.

Comment: You say in the title "prove rigorously" but in the question you say "a picture with some explanation will suffice". In my opinion you must clarify what you are asking to get an adequate answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "vector" or by "scalar"? I guess most mathematicians would think that the statements you mention form a part of the definitions of the words (as in @Eupraxis1981's answer).

Comment: Yea, that's why im confused. These seem like definitions yet our packet calls it a theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are defined over a [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), so they axiomatically possess the properties of a [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), namely, commutivity, associativity, distributivity.

Answer (score 0):

A vector space $V$ is defined over a field, say $K.$ The first one, $c\left(-1\cdot A\right)=c\left(-1\right)\cdot A$ is just the fact that vector multiplication and field multiplication are compatible actions (this seems like a specific example of the third one you list), which is true by the axioms of a vector space. For these kinds of proofs, I think a good place to start would be the axioms of a vector space. I feel like some of these are true by definition of vector space, like the distributive one. It is given that field addition $+K\times K\to K$ is left and right distributive over vector multiplication $\cdot:K\times V\to V.$